# WebStorm cannot resolve relative paths, but imports work fine

Tags: sass, webstorm

There is problem with WebStorm warning appears in *.scss file (not CSS module) which imports another* SCSS files (not modules).

[image]

Weirdness #1:

- It resolves SCSS file in the same folder by relative path, but can't do the same with SCSS files in sub-folders

Weirdness #2:

- It's resolved successfully by another IDE (e.g. VS Code).

Weirdness #3 and main:

- It's compiled successfully when I use npm build or npm start.

And it can be resolved visually in IDE when I add ./ before relative path. But there is info in docs: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/#imports that @import "style.scss" and @import "./style.scss" are identical.

Comment: can't see any issues when using relative imports like `@import 'bar/foo'` in Webstorm. Can you check if you can reproduce the issue in a new project after copying your `.scss` files to it?

Comment: @lena I downgraded WebStorm to 2021.3.3 and made no changes in code and it solved my issue. But I'm still not sure it was wrong IDE's settings or a bug.